# Encountered the symbol "="

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I'm getting an error when using the below PL/SQL:

```
 1  DECLARE
      2   var_salary number(6);
      3   var_emp_id number(6) =7788;
      4  BEGIN
      5   SELECT sal
      6   INTO var_salary
      7   FROM emp
      8   WHERE emp.empno =var_emp_id;
      9  dbms_output.put_line(var_salary);
     10* end;


SQL> /
 var_emp_id number(6) =7788;
                      *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 23:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
:= ; not null default character
The symbol ":= was inserted before "=" to continue.
```

I'm a beginner and can't work out why I'm getting an error

Comment: You got a clear error which tells you to put the colon **:** symbol in front of equal to **=** symbol right which is used to assign a value to that field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` is an equality operator, but you're using it in an assignment. The assignment operator is `:=`.

Change:

```
var_emp_id number(6) =7788;
```

to

```
var_emp_id number(6) := 7788;
```

It's worth noting that the error message you got gave you a few hints about what's wrong; it told you the line and column and then that you'd got the operator incorrect:

> The symbol ":= was inserted before "=" to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Use assignment operator (:=)  instead of equality operator (=) in line number 3