# PL/SQL Trigger cursor error

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle10g

I'm almost new to triggers. I have a problem with this trigger. I want to insert, in the projects table, a new city (projects.plocations) that is one of the selected by the definition of the cursor 'cur'. 
When I execute, i got this error:

*12/21    PLS-00103: Trovato il simbolo "=" anzichÚ uno dei seguenti.*

Translation: *12/21    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol “=” when expecting one of the following:*

But, if I execute without the lines, it gives me no errors:

```
**if (:new.plocation := city) then
c=1;
end if;**
```

Can you tell me why?

```
create or replace trigger tr_projects
before insert on projects
for each row
declare
exc exception;
cursor cur is (
    (select dlocation from dept_locations) minus (select plocation from projects));
city varchar(30);
c number(1):=0;
begin
open cur;
loop
fetch cur into city;
exit when cur%notfound;
if (:new.plocation := city) then
    c=1;
end if;
end loop;
close cur;
if c=0 then
raise exc;
end if;
exception
when exc then
raise_application_error(-20001,'Unknown city');
end;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encountered the symbol "="](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066540/encountered-the-symbol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if (:new.plocation := city) then
    c=1;
end if;
```

to

```
if (:new.plocation = city) then
    c := 1;
end if;
```

`:=` is the assignment operator, `=` is the comparison operator

Comment: Ok. Done. But it shows again the same error and the same line.

Comment: If you use the information provided in this answer to the line below @Franktrt, could you solve your issue?

Comment: Done. Thank you. It is c:=1 in the line below.
It shows no errors now.